I want to add retry logic and. refactor the code in the python socket connect code
I have the below Python code which checks whether the ssh host is up or not:
`for hostname ,ipaddr in host_dict.items():       
            if tcp_conn.tcp_port_is_open(ipaddr, constants.TCP_PORT, constants.TCP_TIMEOUT) == True :
                print("host is Up")                
            else:
                print("Host is Down")`

I want to add retry logic which checks if the host is having some issue then it reconnects and checks whether it is up or not, the retry count will be 3.
I tried running the code and it works fine, but i want to add the retry logic in case the host is down or having some issues then retry should try to connect again with the host.

I'm not sure why you want to check if the port is open before doing the connect. Just try to connect (maybe with timeout). If it fails, retry the connect after some time if you think this will help. Basically a "tcp_port_is_open" would not do anything different, it would try to connect. You cannot get any better than this from remote, unless you have some additional visibility into the destination, like some monitoring which gives you information about the remote hosts status. But you can add such visibility only if you control the destination host.

@SteffenUllrich tcp_port_is_open is a function that calls connect in another python file.

Does this answer your question? How to retry after exception?

I usually implement retry behavior like this:
retries = 3
success = False
while retries and not success:
    if check_something():
        success = True
    else:
        # do something, maybe time.sleep()
    retries -= 1

# do something depending on the value of success

You often don't need a success variable, especially within a function or loop where you can use break/continue/return. Here's how I might implement retry behavior for your code:
for hostname, ipaddr in host_dict.items():
    retries = 3
    while retries:
        if tcp_conn.tcp_port_is_open(ipaddr, constants.TCP_PORT, constants.TCP_TIMEOUT):
            print(f"Host {hostname} is up")
            continue
        retries -= 1
    print(f"Could not connect to {hostname} after 3 retries")

